# Current line of code executed by the CPU at a particular point of time

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, macos

I am writing an application for OSX in Objective-C. It is a multithreaded application. One particular thread does a job(captures screen, writes data in TCP socket) and sleeps for 200 milliseconds. It wakes up and does the same job again. This runs continuously until the program quits. There is another thread which reads data from a TCP socket. The main thread just shows the UI.

When I run this program continuously for sometime, after a while ( after ~2-3 mins) the 200ms sleep of the first thread increases drastically to 5 seconds or 10 seconds. I understand that, when another thread is running, the sleep time of the first thread may extend. I added multiple log prints to the second thread. It seems my second thread is not blocking the CPU.

When the sleep time is continuing for an extended period, I want to know which line of code is executed by the CPU other than my first thread. **Is it possible to know the current line of code executed by the CPU at a particular point of time?** This will help me debug the problem.

UPDATE :

To narrow things down, I created a simple program which just prints an integer(auto incremented) every 200ms. Even in this simple program, the issue is reproducible. After some 300-400 iterations, method call time increases to ~10 sec (i.e., integer is not printed every 200 ms. It is printed after about ~10sec each time)

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    Screen* screen = [[Screen alloc] init];
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(firstMethod) toTarget:screen withObject:nil];
}

@end

------------------------------------
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Screen : NSObject

-(void) firstMethod;
-(void) secondMethod;

@end

----------------------------
#import "Screen.h"

@implementation Screen
int i=0;
dispatch_queue_t another_queue;

-(Screen*) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        another_queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.test.timer", NULL);
    }
    return self;
}


-(void) firstMethod {
    i++;
    NSLog(@"i value : %d",i);
    [self secondMethod];
}

-(void) secondMethod {
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 200 * NSEC_PER_MSEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, another_queue, ^(void){
        [self firstMethod];
    });
}

@end
```

Comment: For sleeping, I used [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:]
I also tried dispatch_after() with the same result.

Comment: You can use `trace(1)` to get this kind of information from your apps, and even easier, you can use Instruments for it. That said, you should probably use a proper timer and not a thread that's sleeping to do this.

Comment: @JasonCoco,
1. I assume trace(1) must be inserted inside my code. Where will I add this line in my code? I am not aware of the line that is being executed(rather blocking the CPU) when the thread sleeps.
2. I tried Instruments, when the thread sleeps, CPU goes to 0% and I couldn't understand what it means. Does that mean my thread is waiting for some resource?
3. To avoid sleep, I even tried dispatch_after(). I got the same result(extended time before the job is executed again) with that too.

Comment: No, you don't have to insert it, it's a utility. Ultimately, it's the utility that Instruments uses. See `man trace` on the command line for more information. I think you should run Instruments. Try starting with the System Trace template or maybe the MultiCore template. That will give you all the processor events, including system traps, thread context switches, GCD info, scheduler info, etc

Comment: Also, you shouldn't ever sleep your thread. The scheduler doesn't make any guarantees there and may do strange things with this pattern. You should use a timer. There are a lot of options. You can use `NSTimer` in Foundation, schedule a timer in CoreFoundation on the run loop, use GCD timer sources, or use the super low-level kevent timers and even use that to multiplex with your sockets and run everything on a single thread. Whatever you choose, however, I strongly suggest abandoning the sleep/wait strategy.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @JasonCoco. I will try trace or/and Instruments and let you know.

Comment: @JasonCoco - what 'strange things'?

Comment: @JasonCoco, I have edited the original post and added another observation. Can you please have a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

As you have described your app, 'the current line of code executed by the CPU' is going to be 'none' most of the time, ie. CPU use will indeed be 0%.  If a GUI thread is not actually handling mouse/KB input and other threads are waiting for network data or sleeping, nothing is happening and there is no code that needs to be executed, so CPU is not required.

There is nothing intrinsically wrong with Sleep().  The thread that calls it is blocked until the interval has expired, as determined by a shared timer queue in the kernel.  No other threads/timers/whatever are required and the call/return context of the caller is preserved, (unlike using an explicit timer). A sleeping thread becomes ready, (not necessarily running, as described by others in comments), after the passed interval plus some ms timer jitter.  Often, threads that have been  waiting on something, (sleep timer, I/O or inter-thread synchro), are given a temporary priority-boost anyway when the become ready, and are liikely to be set running reasonably quickly unless your box is overloaded with running higher-priority threads, (which it seems it is not if the CPU use drops to 0 during the sleep).

Your aparrent problem with 'the 200ms sleep of the first thread increases drastically to 5 seconds or 10 seconds' is very unlikely to be some artifact of the Sleep() call itself. Much more likely is that the interval passed has actually been corrupted by some bug or it is not the Sleep() call that is generating the extra delay.  Maybe your network send call is blocking for extended periods because the server or link is slow and the network buffers are full?

Comment: Dear Martin James, I have edited my original post and added some more observations. Can you please check it?